# Trying to convert nvarchar stored as datetime to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL date field that is stored as `nvarchar(max)`.

Example: `4/7/2016 12:50:03 AM`

I need to convert this to `int`.

I have this: `cast(convert(char(8), DateField,112) as int)`

but I'm getting an error message

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5/22/201' to data type int

Obviously, `/` isn't an `int` character. Any suggestions??

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?  Please store them as their appropriate datatypes...  This is not only a massive amount of overhead just to store the data, but it causes numerous complications when trying to query data.   That being said... What exactly are you expecting an `INT` representation of this to be...?

Comment: @Siyual: `CONVERT(INT, getdate())` returns the number of days since 1900-01-01.

Comment: @RossPresser Yes, but that doesn't mean that the OP wants his `INT` representations of the dates to be that.  He could want `20160407` or `472016` or the EPOCH time, or even the number of minutes since the last Star Wars movie.  It's completely undefined...

Comment: "I" am not storing dates as NVARCHAR(MAX). That just happens to be what I'm dealing with. I want to convert the string 'March 1, 2016' to come back as 20160301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you cast the varchar to a date it will work
cast(convert(char(8),cast(DateField as datetime),112) as int)

Comment: Yep. This did exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can `replace` the slashes with blanks:

```
CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8),DateField,112),'/','') as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should convert it to `DATETIME`, then convert that to `INT`. And don't count on the date portion being any particular length -- depending on the month and day of month, it can be from 8 to 10 chars long.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (datefield VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @T VALUES ('4/7/2016 12:50:03 AM')
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, DateField) AS INT) FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a chain of conversions:  string --> datetime --> string --> int

```
cast(convert(char(8), convert(datetime, DateField, 101), 112) as int)
```

You might be able to rely on implicit conversions along the chain, but I prefer being explicit.